# EF 6 dynamically create inner join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using Entity framework 6.
I need to pass in a two table names and create a LINQ query that I will be able to use to populate a Kendo Datasource.

This is the code that I am currently trying to change to dynamic.

```
var entryPoint = (from pd in db.Employees
                              join od in db.MessageEmployees on pd.EmpID equals od.EmployeeID into t
                              from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              where pd.Class == clssID && pd.IsInactive == 0
                              orderby pd.Class
                              select new
                              {
                                  ClassID = pd.Class,
                                  pd.FirstName,
                                  pd.LastName,
                                  pd.EmpID,
                                  pd.EmployeeID,
                                  EmpMessageID = rt.EmployeeID
                              });
            //IQueryable<Employee> emps = db.Employees;
            DataSourceResult result = entryPoint.ToDataSourceResult(request, empl => new HierachyEmployee
            {
                ClassID = empl.ClassID,
                FirstName = empl.FirstName,
                LastName = empl.LastName,
                EmpID = empl.EmpID,
                IsChecked = empl.EmpMessageID != null
            });
            return Json(result);
```

I need db.MessageEmployees and db.Employees to be dynamic.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Let's start with why you think they need to be dynamic.

Comment: The code will retrieve the data for a generic hierarchial grid that will be used within our application.  The controller will be passing in the names of the tables we are going to use for each of the grids.

Comment: Not really something that LINQ was designed for.  You might try dynamic LINQ, or build your query up yourself and execute it via SqlQuery.